# Profiling high-scoring clusters in a multi-dimensional feature space

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, svm, high-dimensional

I have a large amount of samples, which have a multi-imensional feature vector associated with them.

Each sample has a "score", and the length of the feature vector is substantial (n>100, and in another use-case n>10,000).

The number of samples is quite large - say in the tens of thousands, at least.

I'm interested in detecting groups of features that create a high contrast on the score.

For a concrete example:

1. Samples are the amount of questions a user asks on a StackExchange
2. features are a mix of: country, browser, connection speed, upvotes, age, gender, education, etc...
3. I'm looking for interesting, high scoring clusters. "female users from the UK, aged 25, and browsing from firefox ask an unusually large amount of questions, as well as Israeli males that study computer science"

Note that the score is continuous, and the features may be a mix of categorical (country), ordinal (education level), integer (age) and continuous (income) values.

Can you guys point me at some relevant algorithms / implementations?

P.S. what I considered so far, but found lacking:

1. K-means - but the samples don't have a distance between them, just a score for each sample
2. Decision trees - but my score is not binary, or categorical...
3. Support Vector Regression - then observing the feature weights. But this will not detect complex clusters, only obvious first-degree phenomena.

Comment: What *is* a cluster then to you? K-means doesn't work, and the other techniques you mentioned are not clustering techniques at all...

Comment: I'm looking for a "cluster" in the sense of groups of samples that are "close" to each other, in the sense that they have similar features, and that are all "high scoring" in the sense of the score allocated for each sample.
SVM and Decision Trees are not clustering algorithms, but one can use the resulting feature weights to get a clue as to "first-order" possible clusters.

I'm looking for a better solution than that, of course.

Comment: try to get a more precise notion of "close", and you may evenutally be able to use e.g. hierarchical clustering.